# how to launch WhatsApp from browser

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I am working on a voice bot where I want to launch the WhatsApp from the browser.
As per the [Whatsapp Faq](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013), I found that `whatsapp://app` will launch the application.
But nothing works in the case of me. (in android).
Could anyone help me to launch the application from the browser (But not the chat composer)

Comment: have you tried with https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Comment: @Ovidash Tried that too. But it directly opens up a chat. All I need is to open the whatsapp application which contains the conversation list. Anyways, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

use this link:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=**yyyyyyyyy&text=Hello! I want a reservation

Where:
** is the country prefix
yyyyyyyyy is the telephone number without spaces.

I think now is the browser standar for that. This link allow to open web browser on desktop too.
It works for me on mobile and desktop.